# Android.PowerMock. Folder "test" - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter

Tags: android, mockito, powermock

I want to write a unit test for a static method in an Android app. I use Mockito and PowerMock for this.

In the Android folder `test` (*myproject/app/src/test/java/com/myproject/android/*) i have this unit test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StringUtil.class)
public class StringUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void isCorrectEmailStub() {
        mockStatic(StringUtil.class);
        String INCORRECT_EMAIL_TO_CHECK = "incorrect_email_some.com";
        when(StringUtil.isCorrectEmail(INCORRECT_EMAIL_TO_CHECK)).thenReturn(true);
        assertThat(StringUtil.isCorrectEmail(INCORRECT_EMAIL_TO_CHECK), is(true));
    }
}
```

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.21"
}
```

The project gets build successfully, but when I try to run the test `isCorrectEmailStub`, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor5.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:48)
>         at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:251)
>         at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139)
>         at org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.getInstanceForClassLoader(AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.java:41)
>         at org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.create(AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.java:35)
>         at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.getMockingFrameworkReporter(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:140)
>         at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:119)
>         at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>         at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
>         at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>         at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
>         at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
>         at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
>         at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.exceptions.Reporter
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:190)
>         at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:77)
>         at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Why do I get this error and how can I prevent it?

Comment: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work only with Mockito version < 2.0. This work:

```
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
```